# Authorization error while running db.command("usersInfo") in a mongodb atlas instance

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

getting "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on admin to execute command" on Atlas mongo db instance.

And while I run the same command on a local mongo DB instance, I don't get the error.

> > > db.command("usersInfo")

Comment: This is vague to answer. How are creating mongoclient is it with root user or less privileged user? How are you doing it in local? By local do you mean local mongo instance or remote mongo instance from your local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected in Atlas shared tier (M0/M2/M5). See:

- [Unsupported Commands in M0/M2/M5 Clusters](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/)
- [Unsupported Commands in M10+ Clusters](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands-paid-tier-clusters/)

Regarding `usersInfo`:

```
This command can only be called with arguments:
{user: <MYUSER>, db: 'admin'}
```

Local MongoDB instances wouldn't have this restriction because it's entirely your responsibility to secure the deployment, and thus not subject to strict secure default settings like Atlas.